# What is the structure of iodide of Millon's base?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, structural-formula, halides

In qualitative analysis, $\ce{NH4+}$ ions are confirmed using Nessler's         reagent:-

$$\ce{NH4+ + 2[HgI4]^{2−} + 4OH− → HgO·Hg(NH2)I ↓ + 7I^{−} + 3H2O}$$

The brown precipitate formed is called iodide of Millon's base.  It is also written as  $\ce{3HgO.Hg(NH3)2I2}$ and as $\ce{NH2.Hg2I3}$. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_tetraiodomercurate(II))).

But its structure is present differently in different sites:-

1. [Source 1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=negDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA411&lpg=PA411&dq=iodide%20of%20millon%27s%20base%20structure&source=bl&ots=dXuOAtEtCa&sig=S2q0-6j16wcJSEEV5j0d949Rzf8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio5J7q-aDKAhUTGo4KHf87CCIQ6AEIPDAG#v=onepage&q=iodide%20of%20millon's%20base%20structure&f=false) - ionic form

[image]

2. [Source 2](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ob8MAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=iodide%20of%20millon%27s%20base%20structure&source=bl&ots=pRjHCNXRL_&sig=PTTGyQM32Pa9-1qZ5rPrJQaQcfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio5J7q-aDKAhUTGo4KHf87CCIQ6AEIPjAH#v=onepage&q=iodide%20of%20millon's%20base%20structure&f=false)  - Here the reaction is given differently:-

$$\ce{([K2]HgI4 <=> 2KI + HgI2) * 2}$$
$$\ce{HgI2 + NH3 -> Hg[NH2]I + NH4I}$$
$$\ce{Hg[NH2]I + HgI2 -> NH2Hg2I3 }$$
$$\ce{[K2]HgI4 + 2NH3 -> NH2Hg2I3 + 4KI + KH4I }$$

structure -

[image]

3. [Source 3](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=D-gDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=iodide%20of%20millon%27s%20base%20structure&source=bl&ots=NyZqZZfswl&sig=-7nBQEtyv6X-szqUHtgidSzvYdI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio5J7q-aDKAhUTGo4KHf87CCIQ6AEIQTAI#v=onepage&q=iodide%20of%20millon's%20base%20structure&f=false)- non ionic form

[image]

4. [Source 4](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=1OgRECl_nwMC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=iodide%20of%20millon%27s%20base%20structure&source=bl&ots=34ZJ6mjNUu&sig=fiQC57VduQsaQKSfE61S3ATY4-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio5J7q-aDKAhUTGo4KHf87CCIQ6AEIODAF#v=onepage&q=iodide%20of%20millon's%20base%20structure&f=false) - Hydrate form; Here also the reaction is different:-
   $$\ce{[K2]HgI4 -> 2KI + HgI2}$$
   $$\ce{HgI2 + NH3 -> Hg[NH2]I + HI}$$
   [image]

This site also says that its structure is still uncertain. Various other structure has been proposed:-

[image]

So, what is the correct reaction, correct formula and correct structure of iodide of Millon's base?

Comment: http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0365110X51000453 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercuric_amidochloride

Comment: @permeakra, the paper showed the structure of millon base. Not the iodide of millon's base.

Comment: the second link provides structure for similar compounds, chloride of milton's base . It should give an idea, I believe. Anyway, it is absolutely clear, that non of structures provided in the question has anything to do with real life: the iodide is definitely polymeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, ignore any monomeric formula. The compound is definitely polymeric.

The literature contains hints for existence of two separate lines of compounds. The first one is salts of polyamidomercury: $\ce{[Hg(NH2)]_{n}A_{n}}${[1](http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0365110X51000866)} with mercury-amide chains in the structure, and $\ce{(Hg2N)_{n}A_{n}}$ with structure based on crystoballite {[2](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.201305545/abstract)}{[3](http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0365110X51000453)}

It seems thatn the lines are not distinguished in earlier literature, but recent researchers use the words "Millon's base salts" for $\ce{(Hg2N)_{n}A_{n}}$ only.