# On basic mercury salts

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, salt, mercury, chemical-formula

$\ce{HgCO3.3HgO}$ and $\ce{HgO.Hg(NH2)Cl}$ are called basic mercury carbonate and basic mercury amidochloride, respectively. I found [this thread](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=10019) on the former; I've only seen the latter as the product of a qualitative test in one of my textbooks, and Google yields nothing on it.

Is "basic metal salt" a general term for salts of the form $\ce{M_yB_x.M_2O_x}$(M the metal, B some anion with valency y, x the valency of the metal) or is it just for some compounds of mercury? If it's just for mercury, which ones more are there?

Are there any "acidic salt" analogues? If so, what general formula do they have?

Comment: Metal hydrogen sulfates MHSO4 are generally acidic

Comment: Also, see this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/133364/why-does-hgcl2-react-with-hco3-but-not-with-co32

Comment: [Iodide of Millon's base has the formula $\ce{HgO.Hg(NH2)I}$](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43573/what-is-the-structure-of-iodide-of-millons-base). So, your compound of "basic mercury amidochloride" should analogically be called chloride of Millon's base.

Comment: @NilayGhish: I actually do know about the terms in your first comment; I just wondered if there was a separate subclass or something, because I was seeing so many mercuric salts with HgO in them temed as such.

Comment: No, there is no separate subclass. Salts which contains hydroxide with other anions are called basic salts and ones which contains hydrogen are called acidic salts. But this is a very crude classification because the above compounds are also considered basic salts when neither of them contains hydroxide. I assume alkali compounds have been used in their making and/or the overall pH is basic.

Comment: @NilayGhosh: that makes sense, but there's also basic mercury sulfate, HgSo4.2HgO, made by reacting mercuric nitrate and the sulfate anion. That doesn't smack of a basic medium.

Comment: [The technical name for that compound is mercuric subsulfate or mercury oxonium sulfate because of presence of polymeric oxonium cation $\ce{[Hg3O2]_{x}^{2+}}$ in a 2D infinite layer. The sulfate ion lies within the infinite mesh of cation lattice](https://www.drugfuture.com/chemdata/mercuric-subsulfate.html). So, we should try to avoid the word "basic" as it might create confusion. Try using the proper name. For ex: FeOOH is called iron oxide hydroxide. It also contains hydroxide but nobody calls it "basic iron oxide".

Comment: @NilayGhosh: just to be clear; so the earlier point about the basic pH isn't valid in every case?

Comment: It depends. One calls them "basic" if it satisfies one of the 3 criteria: (1) If it contains hydroxide in its formula (2) Its overall pH is basic (3)It is made using alkali compounds. But then again, this whole classification create confusion. One more example: [aq. soln. of KMnO4 is slightly basic. Why? Because, since it is prepared in the presence of alkali, the product might contain some leftover alkali and hence the solution is basic](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151227/why-is-the-aqueous-solution-of-kmno4-slightly-basic) But nobody calls it "basic" potassium permanganate.

Comment: @NilayGhosh: Great, that last comment was really comprehensive, thanks. I get the thing about not using this; it's way too fuzzy a definition and it's unnecessary. But it comes up multiple times in inorganic analysis, so i guess asking about it is warranted.

Answer (score 1):

There exist plenty of basic salts. For example,

1. Copper produces a "simple" copper carbonate $\ce{CuCO3}$ as high $\ce{CO2}$ pressure. At lower pressures, the following basic copper carbonates are produced : $\ce{Cu3(CO3)2(OH)2}$ or $\ce{Cu2CO3(OH)2}$ (malachite), depending on the partial $\ce{CO2}$ pressure. Other copper salts produce basic copper salts like : $\ce{Cu2NO3(OH)3}$ , $\ce{Cu4(OH)6Cl2}$, $\ce{Cu4(OH)6SO4}$ .
2. Zinc produces the two following basic zinc carbonates, according to the chosen pH : $\ce{Zn5(OH)6(CO3)2}$ or $\ce{Zn2CO3(OH)2}$
3. Iron(III) produces also basic salts like $\ce{FeSO4(OH)}$ which is produced by air oxidation of iron(II) sulfate. Dilution of a ferric acetate solution produces a precipitate of basic acetate $\ce{Fe(CH3COO)(OH)2}$
4. Aluminum solutions are often hydrolyzed producing basic salts. In the case of acetate, it gives a precipitate of basic acetate $\ce{Al(CH3COO)(OH)2}$
5. Cobalt chloride solutions treated by cold NaOH solutions give a precipitate of basic chloride $\ce{CoClOH}$ When treated by carbonate solutions they produce a great variety of basic carbonates.
   This list is not exhaustive.

Comment: Could you verify the criteria detailed in the comments above? That solves my problem. This answer is great, btw

Comment: @Harry Holmes. Nilay Ghosh proposes three criteria, which can be discussed. 1) A basic salt must contain a hydroxide compound. No ! It may contain oxide ion $\ce{O^{2-}}$ like the mineral goethite $\ce{FeOOH}$. 2) Its overall pH is basic. It does not make any sense, as a precipitate or any solid does not have a pH value. 3) A basic salt is made using alcali compounds. NO ! It may be made using Barium hydroxide. And the example of impure potassium permanganate is poor.  It is basic when insure may mean that it is not basic as a pure compound.

Comment: I see. I could make a point for the second criterion, though; the basic pH might refer to the pH of the salt in solution. Either way, could you specify an alternate list of criteria? I know there aren't hard and fast rules for these common names, but a rough sketch would be helpful.

Comment: @Harry Holmes. The pH of a solution made with an insoluble salt is a non-sense. It may happen that there is not even one atom of the insoluble salt per liter water. As to the possible rules about basic salts, I am afraid there are none.